# Voltar para o inicio caso o tamanho não seja atingido

Tags: java

Galera, recebi essa semana um trabalho da facul muito foda e estou com problema numa parte dele...
É o seguinte, eu tenho que montar um sistema para uma loja de pulseiras, que dá a opção de escolha de tamanho e pingentes, cada pingente e tamanho com seu comprimento e preço.
Até agora o qeu eu aprendi foi o básico de JAVA por isso a dificuldade de montar este sistema. Porém eu consegui tranquilo, só estou com problema que não sei como fazer para ele repetir as partes de escolha de pingente, caso o tamanho total de pingente que o usuário escolha não feche o tamanho da pulseira..
O código está bem poluído pelo fato desse ser o conhecimento que eu tenho no momento...
Se alguém tiver saco e me dizer como fazer estou aguardando. Abraços!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bichara_System{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o tamanho da pulseira\nPequena (17cm) - R$180,00\nMédia (18cm) - R$200,00\nGrande (20cm) - R$240,00");
        String pulseira = in.nextLine();
        int valorpulseira = 0;
        int tamanhopulseira = 0;
        if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("pequena")){
            pulseira = "pequena";
            valorpulseira = 180;
            tamanhopulseira = 17;
            System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\nAgora escolha o pingente:");
        } else if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("media")){
            pulseira = "media";
            valorpulseira = 200;
            tamanhopulseira = 18;
            System.out.println("Total: R$200,00\nAgora escolha o pingente:");
        } else if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("grande")){
            pulseira = "grande";
            valorpulseira = 240;
            tamanhopulseira = 20;
            System.out.println("Total: R$240,00\nAgora escolha o pingente:");
        }
        System.out.println("Bichinhos (1,3cm) - R$225,00\nBonequinhos (1,5cm) - R$185,00\nBerloques (0,5cm) - R$200,00\nCubinhos (1cm) - R$190,00\nRolinho (2cm) - Prata, Pedra e Esmaltados.");
        String pingente = in.nextLine();
        int valorpingente = 0;
        double tamanhopingente = 0;
        int valor = 0;
        double tamanhofinal = 0;
        if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("bichinhos")){
            pingente = "bichinhos";
            valorpingente = 225;
            tamanhopingente = 1.3;
            System.out.println("Quantos?");
            int qntsbichinhos = in.nextInt();
            double tamanhobichinhos = qntsbichinhos*tamanhopingente;
            if(tamanhobichinhos > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de bichinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
            } else {
                int valorbichinhos = qntsbichinhos*valorpingente;
                valor = valorpulseira+valorbichinhos;
                tamanhofinal = qntsbichinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
                System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
            }
        }
        double tamanhofinal2 = 0;
        if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("bonequinhos")){
            pingente = "bonequinhos";
            valorpingente = 185;
            tamanhopingente = 1.5;
            System.out.println("Quantos?");
            int qntsbonequinhos = in.nextInt();
            double tamanhobonequinhos = qntsbonequinhos*tamanhopingente;
            if(tamanhobonequinhos > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de bonequinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
            } else {
                int valorbonequinhos = qntsbonequinhos*valorpingente;
                valor = valorpulseira+valorbonequinhos;
                tamanhofinal2 = qntsbonequinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
                System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
            }
        }
        double tamanhofinal3 = 0;
        if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("berloques")){
            pingente = "berloques";
            valorpingente = 200;
            tamanhopingente = 0.5;
            System.out.println("Quantos?");
            int qntsberloques = in.nextInt();
            double tamanhoberloques = qntsberloques*tamanhopingente;
            if(tamanhoberloques > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de berloques que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
            } else {
                int valorberloques = qntsberloques*valorpingente;
                valor = valorpulseira+valorberloques;
                tamanhofinal3 = qntsberloques*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
                System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
            }
        }
        double tamanhofinal4 = 0;
        if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("cubinhos")){
            pingente = "cubinhos";
            valorpingente = 190;
            tamanhopingente = 1;
            System.out.println("Quantos?");
            int qntscubinhos = in.nextInt();
            double tamanhocubinhos = qntscubinhos*tamanhopingente;
            if(tamanhocubinhos > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de cubinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
            } else {
                int valorcubinhos = qntscubinhos*valorpingente;
                valor = valorpulseira+valorcubinhos;
                tamanhofinal4 = qntscubinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
                System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
            }
        }
        double tamanhofinal5 = 0;
        if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("rolinho")){
            pingente = "rolinho";
            tamanhopingente = 2;
            System.out.println("Escolha o material:\nPrata - R$150,00\nPedras - R$220,00\nEsmaltados - R$198,00");
            String rolinho = in.nextLine();
            if(rolinho.toLowerCase().equals("prata")){
                valorpingente = 150;
            }if(rolinho.toLowerCase().equals("pedras")){
                valorpingente = 220;
            }if(rolinho.toLowerCase().equals("esmaltados")){
                valorpingente = 198;
            }
            System.out.println("Quantos?");
            int qntsrolinhos = in.nextInt();
            double tamanhorolinhos = qntsrolinhos*tamanhopingente;
            if(tamanhorolinhos > tamanhopulseira){
                System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de rolinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
            } else {
                int valorcubinhos = qntsrolinhos*valorpingente;
                valor = valorpulseira+valorcubinhos;
                tamanhofinal4 = qntsrolinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
                System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Você deseja adquirir um suporte de segurança pelo preço de R$95,00? (Sim ou Não)");
        String suporte = in.nextLine();
        int valorsuporte = 0;
        if(suporte.toLowerCase().equals("sim")){
            valorsuporte = 95;
            valor = valorpulseira+valorpingente+valorsuporte;
            System.out.println("Total: "+valor);
        } else {
            valor = valorpulseira+valorpingente+valorsuporte;
            System.out.println("Total: "+valor);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Dei uma [identada](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/10au/indent.html) no código pra ficar mais fácil de ler, se eu prejudiquei alguma coisa sem querer favor reverter a edição, ok?

Comment: Ok, qualquer coisa eu reverto xD

Comment: Comece quebrando seu código em métodos menores. `escolherPulseira`, `escolherPingente`, `checaTamanho`, `escolherMaterial`, `adquirirSuporte`, etc. Se você já teve aulas de orientação a objetos é interessante criar classes de modelo também (`Pulseira`, `Pingente`, etc).

Comment: Em posse de métodos como esse você pode fazer algo do tipo `do {montaPulseira(pulseira, bichinhos);} while (pulseira.getTamanho() > tamanhoPulseira)`.

Comment: Pois então, eu não tive aulas sobre isso ainda! Eu até poderia pegar e aprender vendo exemplos na iternet porém eu tenho que fazer o trabalho com o que foi trabalhado em aula. Creio que essa professora sejo meio sem noção de mandar fazer um sistema desses somente usando ifs e switchs e métodos para declarar variaveis... Eu queria fazer algo do tipo `if(TamanhoTotalComPingentes < tamanhoDaPulseiraEscolhida{ refaz o processo de escolha de pingente armazenando o tamanho e o preço do ja escolhido}`

Comment: Guilherme, isso que você está querento fazer é um `goto` (que não existe em Java). A melhor opção ness caso é quebrar em métodos mesmo. Caso você não possa fazer isso (eu faria, sua professora não vai descontar nota por fazer o código da forma correta) você pode cercar todo o pedaço de montagem com um `while (tamanhoPingentes < tamanhoDaPulseiraEscolhida)`, assim ele só sai do laço quando o usuário tiver escolhido uma combinação válida.

Comment: ta mas usando o while ele vai continuar com os dados que já estão armazenados??

Comment: Sim se você declarar a variável fora do escopo do laço.

Comment: Perfeito então. Porém eu não sei quebrar em métodos :/ Tem algum link para me passar? dai caso eu tenha mais problemas eu faço outra pergunta..

Comment: E quanto a loops, isso foi visto em aula? Sem loops e sem recursão (um ou outro) essa repetição que você quer é impossível (a menos que você copie e cole seu código N vezes... baita gambiarra...)

Comment: exatamente ia ficar uma gambiarra do caramba.. Acabei de descobrir que posso usar while, então acho que vou optar pela opção de quebrar em métodos e usar o while. Para isso além de quebrar o código em métodos é só retirar as definições de variáveis de dentro dos IFS e deixar na função principal correto?

Comment: @Guilherme Você não *precisa* quebrar em métodos para usar `while` - seria só uma questão de organização, mas como seu código é essencialmente sequencial não vejo grandes problemas em se ter uma única função gigante. Vou dar um exemplo em resposta.

Comment: @Guilherme Pronto! Gostaria também de acrescentar que - se você fosse quebrar em métodos, você também teria que passar parâmetros e receber um valor de retorno, ou talvez criar campos (provavelmente estáticos) para compartilhar dados entre a `main` e as outras funções. Eventualmente você vai aprender tudo isso, mas não é necessário atropelar as coisas... Dividindo seu código em seções já ajuda bastante, tipo `/* Escolha da pulseira */ código /* Escolha do tipo do pingente */ mais código /* Adquirir suporte */ mais código`

Comment: Olá @Guilherme, apenas adicionando o que  os nobres amigos já disseram, seria bom você dar uma olhada em Orientação à Objetos, como material de apoio deixo aqui o link para à excelente apostila da Caelum: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quer executar certo código, depois repeti-lo se ao final certa condição não for satisfeita, a maneira mais natural é usando um `do...while` (faça X, se a condição Y for verdadeira faça X de novo, etc). Mas também é possível usando um simples `while` (se a condição Y for verdadeira faça X, se a condição Y for verdadeira faça X de novo, etc).

1. Mova tudo o que puder ser repetido para dentro de uma "seção" separada. Por exemplo, seu código:

   ```
   System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\nAgora escolha o pingente:");
   ```

   é problemático porque dessa forma o `Agora escolha o pingente:` só será impresso uma vez (além disso essa frase se repete várias vezes, seria melhor separá-la de qualquer forma). Uma alternativa seria:

   ```
   if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("pequena")){
       pulseira = "pequena";
       valorpulseira = 180;
       tamanhopulseira = 17;
       System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\n");
   } else if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("media")){
       pulseira = "media";
       valorpulseira = 200;
       tamanhopulseira = 18;
       System.out.println("Total: R$200,00\n");
   } else if(pulseira.toLowerCase().equals("grande")){
       pulseira = "grande";
       valorpulseira = 240;
       tamanhopulseira = 20;
       System.out.println("Total: R$240,00\n");
   }

   System.out.println("Agora escolha o pingente:");
   ```
2. Crie uma condição - inicialmente verdadeira - dizendo se é ou não para continuar no *loop*. Então mova seu código pra dentro do *loop* (mantenha as declarações de variáveis fora, para que elas continuem acessíveis para o resto do código, se aplicável):

   ```
   String pingente; // Não leia ainda!
   int valorpingente = 0;
   double tamanhopingente = 0;
   int valor = 0;
   double tamanhofinal = 0;

   boolean continuar1 = true;
   while ( continuar1 ) { // Executa pelo menos uma vez, e repete
                          // enquanto continuar1 não ficar falso

       System.out.println("Agora escolha o pingente:");
       System.out.println("Bichinhos (1,3cm) - R$225,00\nBonequinhos (1,5cm) - R$185,00\nBerloques (0,5cm) - R$200,00\nCubinhos (1cm) - R$190,00\nRolinho (2cm) - Prata, Pedra e Esmaltados.");
       pingente = in.nextLine(); // Agora sim, leia

       if(pingente.toLowerCase().equals("bichinhos")){
           pingente = "bichinhos";
           valorpingente = 225;
           tamanhopingente = 1.3;
           System.out.println("Quantos?");
           int qntsbichinhos = in.nextInt();
           double tamanhobichinhos = qntsbichinhos*tamanhopingente;
           if(tamanhobichinhos > tamanhopulseira){
               System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de bichinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
           } else {
               int valorbichinhos = qntsbichinhos*valorpingente;
               valor = valorpulseira+valorbichinhos;
               tamanhofinal = qntsbichinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
               System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);
           }
       }

       // ... (inserir as outras opções, também adaptadas)
   }
   ```

   (Nota: **não teste esse código ainda** - pois ele entrará num *loop* infinito; veja o próximo item primeiro)
3. Por fim, estabeleça a condição necessária para sair do *loop*. No caso, é se o usuário escolheu um tamanho válido:

   ```
           } else {
               int valorbichinhos = qntsbichinhos*valorpingente;
               valor = valorpulseira+valorbichinhos;
               tamanhofinal = qntsbichinhos*tamanhopingente+tamanhopulseira;
               System.out.println("\nTotal:" +valor);

               continuar1 = false; // Isso fará com que o código não se repita mais
           }
   ```

Comment: Cara perfeita resposta! Mas  teria como me dar mais um exemplo? Pois não se mexer com esse while para eque ele verifique o tamanho total do pingente e ver se esse tamanho é maior que o da pulseira. Pois no meu código, o else faz com que o usuário possa somente preencher a pulseira inteira com um tipo de pingente, como diz aqui: `if(tamanhobichinhos > tamanhopulseira){
            System.out.println("Você escolheu um número de bichinhos que excede o tamanho da pulseira!");
        }` como eu faço para que o while execute essa funcao para poder usar mais pingentes caso ele escolha somente alguns

Comment: Nesse caso, seria melhor perguntar pro próprio usuário se ele quer parar de escolher ou não. Pois se ele escolheu alguns bichinhos e o tamanho está menor que o da pulseira, como o código vai saber se agora ele quer escolher bonequinhos ou se ele já está satisfeito? O que você pode fazer é colocar uma opção a mais de escolha (`sair`) que - se escolhida - faz `continuar1` ficar falso. Aí, a cada escolha, você soma o tamanho x quantidade de cada pingente, e compara o *total* com o tamanho da pulseira. Se exceder, ou você reseta tudo ou você só reseta o último.

Comment: Como a lógica está mais complexa, fica bem mais difícil fazer sem quebrar em funções. A menos que seu exercício exija isso, minha sugestão é adotar um método mais simples mesmo. Eu poderia tentar te ajudar mais, mas infelizmente não posso dedicar muito tempo a isso hoje não (amanhã ou depois eu posso, entretanto).

Comment: Ok. Tentarei de todas as maneiras. Caso não consiga volto a te chamar aqui ;) Obrigado por tudo!

Comment: Voltei para comentar que deu tudo certo! Refiz o código utilizando o while. Vou postar como forma de resposta para quem quiser avaliar e me dar dicas xD Muito obrigado a todos que responderam e ajudaram demais!

Answer (score 2):

Código final com while:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sistema_Bichara{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Primeiro Menu
        System.out.println("Digite o o número referente ao tamanho da pulseira\n1.Pequena (17cm) - R$180,00\n2.Média (18cm) - R$200,00\n3.Grande (20cm) - R$240,00");
        // Incio declaração de variáveis
        int digita = in.nextInt();
        double pagar = 0;
        double valor = 0;
        double valor2 = 0;
        int tamanhopulseira = 0;
        double tamanhototal = 0.0;
        // Fim declaraçaõ de variáveis
        // Inicio de opções de pulseiras e definido seus preços e tamanhos nas variáveis
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            valor += 180;
            tamanhopulseira = 17;
            System.out.println("Total: R$180,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 200;
            tamanhopulseira = 18;
            System.out.println("Total: R$200,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 240;
            tamanhopulseira = 20;
            System.out.println("Total: R$240,00\nAgora escolha o(s) pingente(s):");
            break;
        }
        // Final da escolha da pulseira
        // Inicio da escolha dos 'enfeites' da pulseira com while para não ultrpassar o tamanho máximo da pulseira. Possui opção para ir direto para o pagamento no meio da escolha (caso não queria preencher o tamanho da pulseira inteiro)
        while (digita != 6 && tamanhototal < tamanhopulseira) {
        System.out.println("1.Bichinhos (1,3cm) - R$225,00\n2.Bonequinhos (1,5cm) - R$185,00\n3.Berloques (0,5cm) - R$200,00\n4.Cubinhos (1cm) - R$190,00\n5.Rolinho (2cm) - Prata, Pedra e Esmaltados\n6.Ir para o pagamento");
        digita = in.nextInt();
        switch(digita){
            case 1:
            valor += 225;
            tamanhototal += 1.3;
            break;
            case 2:
            valor += 185;
            tamanhototal += 1.5;
            break;
            case 3:
            valor += 200;
            tamanhototal += 0.5;
            break;
            case 4:
            valor += 190;
            tamanhototal += 1;
            break;
            case 5:
            tamanhototal += 2;
            System.out.println("Escolha o material:\n1.Prata - R$150,00\n2.Pedras - R$220,00\n3.Esmaltados - R$198,00");
            int rolinho = in.nextInt();
            switch(rolinho){
                case 1:
                valor += 150;
                break;
                case 2:
                valor += 220;
                break;
                case 3:
                valor += 198;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(tamanhototal > tamanhopulseira){
            System.out.println("\nTamanho máximo da pulseira atingido\n1.Prosseguir para o pagamento.");
            digita = in.nextInt();
    }

}
//Final escolha dos enfeites
//Começa processo de pagamento
    if(digita==6){
    System.out.println("\nDigite 1 para prosseguir para o pagamento.");
    digita = in.nextInt();
}
//Oferece o suporte de segurança e se dito que sim, acrescenta o valor de 95 reais no preço total do produto
    System.out.println("\nDeseja adquirir um suporte de segurança pelo preço de R$95,00?\n1.Sim\n2.Não");
    digita = in.nextInt();
    if(digita == 1){
        valor += 95;
}
//Continua o processo de pagamento informando o valor total da compra e oferecendo os tipos de pagamento
    System.out.println("\nO preço total da compra fica de: R$"+valor);
    System.out.println("\nA loja oferece os seguintes tipos de pagamento:");
    System.out.println("\n1. À vista com 5% de desconto");
    System.out.println("\n2. 3 vezes no cartão sem acrescimos");
    System.out.println("\n3. 5 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 10% no preço total");
    System.out.println("\n4. 10 vezes no cartão com acresimo de 20% no preço total");
    System.out.println("\nDigite o número da forma de pagamento escolhida.");
    digita = in.nextInt();
    //Pega o pagamento escolhido e aplica o cálculo matemático para descontos ou acrescimos de preço. Também calcula o valor de cada parcela caso seja parcelado.
    switch(digita){
        case 1:
        valor = valor*0.95;
        break;
        case 2:
        pagar = valor/3;
        break;
        case 3:
        valor2 = (valor*110)/100;
        pagar = valor2/5;
        break;
        case 4:
        valor2 = (valor*120)/100;
        pagar = valor2/10;
        break;
            }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total de acordo com o pagamento escolhido
    if (digita == 3){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else if (digita == 4){
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nO valor total da compra ficou de: R$" +valor);
    }
    //Condição para mostrar o valor total e o valor das parcelas se a pessoa escolheu parcelado
    if(digita == 2){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 3 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    digita = in.nextInt();
}  else if(digita == 3){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 5 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    digita = in.nextInt();
}else if(digita == 4){
    System.out.println("\nForma de pagameto: 10 parcelas de R$" +pagar);
    System.out.println("\nA loja aceita os seguintes cartões:\n1.Visa\n2.MasterCard\n3.Rede Shop\n4.American Express\n5.Hipercard\n6.Diners Club International");
    digita = in.nextInt();
}
//Fim do sistema e agradecimento ao cliente
    System.out.println("\nObrigado por comprar conosco!");
}
}
```

Comment: Já que você pediu dicas, aí vão algumas pra tornar seu código mais robusto: 1) Nos `switch`es, use sempre `default` pro caso do usuário escolher uma opção inválida; mesma coisa quando você não testa o que recebeu (ex.: em "Digite 1 para prosseguir para o pagamento"); na prática isso é importante, pra esse exercício não precisa. 2) Seu código do jeito que está alerta quando o tamanho total foi ultrapassado, mas prossegue mesmo assim - o ideal seria testar isso antes de atualizar `valor` e `tamanhoTotal`, por exemplo alertando o usuário, não mexendo nos valores e continuando com o loop.

Comment: (digo que nesse exercício o item 1 não importa porque ele não cobre tratamento de exceções de qualquer forma, então se o usuário digitar `a` quando você espera um número vai dar errado de qualquer forma... melhor não se preocupar com isso por enquanto) No mais, boa implementação, +1